# Introduction of an Array of JSON objects into another JSON using Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

[DealItemCaption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzKmt.png)

[BigDealTicket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg2br.png)

As I am a bit new to Groovy, I would like to ask you about the following question related to JSON concatenation using Groovy (please see as well the attached images about the problem).
I have here a here a JSON input that I would like to reproduce using Groovy:

```
{"isFinancial":false,
 "isPortfolioTransfer":false,
 "type":"ESS",
 "commodity":"Electricity",
 "timezone":"CET",
 "dealDateTime":1466671066373,
 "dealItems":[{"type":"Energy.StandardShape.FixedPrice",
               "locationType":"grid",
               "dealItemUDFs":[],
               "priceType":"fixed",
               "holidayCalendarId":10001,
               "quantityUnitId":26,
               "priceUnitId":12,
               "dealStart":1483267154000,
               "dealEnd":1514716754000,
               "shapeId":2,
               "balancingGroupId":2,
               "locationId":41,
               "quantity":15000,
               "price":30}],
 "brokerFeeCurrencyId":1,
 "dealTypeId":2,
 "internalEntityId":1399,
 "internalTraderId":305,
 "internalPortfolioId":1,
 "buySell":"-1",
 "externalEntityId":1443,
 "priceRegionId":37,
 "label":"Third Deal Ticket as JIRA Test Candidate",
 "comments":"Third Deal Ticket as JIRA Test Candidate"}
```

I have the internal JSON (the one used inside the Array delimited by the [] brackets)generated using JSONBuilder and also the outer JSON is generated without problems via JSONBuilder, however, there seems to be cosmetic issue regarding the allignment of the given output as follows:

```
{"isFinancial":false,
 "isPortfolioTransfer":false,
 "type":"ESS",
 "commodity":"Electricity",
 "timezone":"CET",
 "dealItems":[{"value":"Energy.StandardShape.FixedPrice","key":"type"},
              {"value":"grid","key":"locationType"},
              {"value":[],"key":"dealItemUDFs"},
              {"value":"fixed","key":"priceType"},
              {"value":10001,"key":"holidayCalendarId"},
              {"value":26,"key":"quantityUnitId"},
              {"value":12,"key":"priceUnitId"},
              {"value":1483225200000,"key":"dealStart"},
              {"value":1514674800000,"key":"dealEnd"},
              {"value":2,"key":"shapeId"},
              {"value":1,"key":"balancingGroupId"},
              {"value":42,"key":"locationId"},
              {"value":15000,"key":"quantity"},
              {"value":30,"key":"price"}],
 "dealDateTime":1467116296197,
 "brokerFeeCurrencyId":6,
 "dealTypeId":2,
 "internalEntityId":1399,
 "internalTraderId":306,
 "internalPortfolioId":1,
 "buySellId":"-1",
 "externalEntityId":1443,
 "priceRegionId":37,
 "label":"Latest JIRA Test Case Candidate",
 "comments":"Latest JIRA Test Case Candidate"}
```

Instead of the value-key pairs for dealItems there should be the following
JSON

```
[{"type":"Energy.StandardShape.FixedPrice",
 "locationType":"grid",
 "dealItemUDFs":\[\],
 "priceType":"fixed",
 "holidayCalendarId":10001,
 "quantityUnitId":26,
 "priceUnitId":12,
 "dealStart":1483225200000,
 "dealEnd":1514674800000,
 "shapeId":2,
 "balancingGroupId":1,
 "locationId":42,
 "quantity":15000,
 "price":30}][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `grails.converters.JSON` ?

The following should do exactly what you want:

```
grails.converters.JSON.parse("""
    {"isFinancial":false,
    "isPortfolioTransfer":false,
    "type":"ESS",
    "commodity":"Electricity",
    "timezone":"CET",
    "dealDateTime":1466671066373,
    "dealItems":[{"type":"Energy.StandardShape.FixedPrice",
                 "locationType":"grid",
                 "dealItemUDFs":[],
                 "priceType":"fixed",
                 "holidayCalendarId":10001,
                 "quantityUnitId":26,
                 "priceUnitId":12,
                 "dealStart":1483267154000,
                 "dealEnd":1514716754000,
                 "shapeId":2,
                 "balancingGroupId":2,
                 "locationId":41,
                 "quantity":15000,
                 "price":30}],
    "brokerFeeCurrencyId":1,
    "dealTypeId":2,
    "internalEntityId":1399,
    "internalTraderId":305,
    "internalPortfolioId":1,
    "buySell":"-1",
    "externalEntityId":1443,
    "priceRegionId":37,
    "label":"Third Deal Ticket as JIRA Test Candidate",
    "comments":"Third Deal Ticket as JIRA Test Candidate"}
""")
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much Jim - I will try this solution. By the way one more question: where is this library located? I refer here to the possibilities of importing it to SOAP UI of course

Comment: So you mean that basically if I would like to have the same result for the value under the DealItems key in my big JSON as posted in the second excerpt I just need to use this library? (sorry in case I have not been clear with the previous question, I meant to have the JSON from second excerpt as an array element instead of the one which presents the key-value pairs - both JSONs are generated correctly when taken separately, the problem is with their join). Thanks for understanding

Comment: Apologies, the plugin I mentioned is a grails plugin, which is available here: https://grails.org/wiki/Converters%20Plugin.

Comment: I'm going to look for a pure groovy option if you aren't using grails.